# Yq: Merge two yaml file selecting keys using wildcard character and removing duplicates

Tags: yaml, yq

I want to merge two yaml files using yq in bash script.Selecting only specific keys values , removing duplicates and building a string.

file1.yaml

```
FT1: true
FT2: true
```

file2.yaml

```
FT1: false
FT2: false
FT3: false
FT4: false
Blah1: abc
Blah2: efg
```

Desired Output:

Trying to build a command like below.

- Filter any keys that starts with (FT*)
- join the key=values
- removing FT1, FT2 from file2.yaml
- And building a command for each key=value pair appending it with --from-literal=

  --from-literal=FT1=true --from-literal=FT2=true --from-literal=FT3=false --from-literal=FT4=false

What I have tried so far:

```
yq eval '. | to_entries| .[] | select(.key == "FT*") | [.key, .value] | join("=") file1.yaml
```

The above command output is as below. Not sure how to merge them , remove duplicates from file2 and build the command.

file1.yaml

```
FT1=true
FT2=true
```

file2.yaml

```
FT1=false
FT2=false
FT3=false
FT4=false
```

Answer (score 0):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can `load` the other file, then merge it by adding:

```bash
yq '. + load("file1.yaml") | .[] | select(key == "FT*") | key + "=" + .' file2.yaml
```

```yaml
FT1=true
FT2=true
FT3=false
FT4=false
```

---

You could also convert `to_props` if it suits your use-case:

```bash
yq 'pick(keys | map(select(. == "FT*"))) + load("file1.yaml") | to_props' file2.yaml
```

```
FT1 = true
FT2 = true
FT3 = false
FT4 = false
```